# mysql phpmyadmin accepting 4 character but its real length is int 2

Tags: mysql

i have employee table and its empid length is INT 3 ,

But it accepting more then 3 character ....

How it is possible

(THIS IS TESTED IN PHPMYADMIN)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To cite the [documentation: 10.2. Numeric Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html)

> Another extension is supported by MySQL for optionally specifying the **display width of integer data types** in parentheses following the base keyword for the type (for example, `INT(4)`). This optional display width ***may* be used by applications to display integer values having a width less than the width specified for the column by left-padding them with spaces**. (That is, this width is present in the metadata returned with result sets. **Whether it is used or not is up to the application.**)

and

> The display width **does not constrain the range of values** that can be stored in the column, **nor the number of digits that are displayed** for values having a width **exceeding** that specified for the column

So you see, it is not a restriction that influences the data stored in MySQL but an additional information for applications that retrieve the data.

Comment: +1 Hah, I stand corrected! I always thought this was to specify the byte range, but on second thought, that is most obviously humbug. Live and learn!

Comment: @Pekka: Honestly, I thought the same first ;) But I recognized again that reading documentation really helps :-D